# Short boil and DMS

Tags: beer, boil, ipa, dms

So I just had a small brewing mishap where I added too much hops.  WAY too much.  I somehow mistook my 2oz hop pellet bag for a 1oz bag and added 1.5ounces of chinook instead of .75 .  This brought my first hop addition to over 110 IBU (WHOOPS!).  In my panic, I made the decision to stop the boil early to prevent any further bittering.  Total I boiled for about 35 minutes.

After the fact, I did some research and learned all about DMS and now I'm worried that I have 5 gallons of bitter corn.

The beer is an American IPA, about 1.058.  On a scale of 1 to f*cked, how bad is it?  What else should I have done in this situation?

Comment: That was a great story!

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that your recipe is all-grain from some of your previous questions, but if it is an extract recipe you probably don't need to worry since most of the DMS boiled off.  A little over a month ago I made a hefe (from extract) and only had a 15 minute boil time.  Neither me, nor anyone who has tasted it can detect any DMS.

If it's all-grain, what percentage of your grain bill is pilsner malt?  If it's not the majority of the grain I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Thanks Room3, you are correct, this was an all grain batch.  The grain bill was 10lbs of American 2row, .75 Carapils and .25 caramel 120

Comment: Room3 is right-- pilsner malt is often the culprit behind dms if the boil was short.  You'll probably be fine.  Smell and taste it after primary.  If it tastes decent, you can probably save it by dry hopping the hell out of it.

Answer (score 3):

With the grist bill you used, there's very little chance of DMS.  Even with pils malt, a long boil is not always needed to prevent DMS.  There's more chance of DMS the lighter your malt is.  I've found that vigor of boil is at least as important as length of boil.  I do a very vigorous boil and I can't recall ever having goteen DMS with a 60 min. boil.

Comment: This was going to be my answer too. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have completed the boiling process. I am still a novice but I would think that, on balance, the boil is more important than the bitterness. Someone out there may have suggestions for countering bitterness by adding some other flavour in a secondary fermentation, perhaps.

Would fishing out a proportion of the hops with a sieve have made a difference? Perhaps things had progressed too far to prevent bittering, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response Weisel.  Good idea about the seive, although I added pelletized hops directly into the boil and probably don't have anything fine enough to fish them out.  I'm thinknig now I should have finished out the boil and just made another batch of MUCH lower IBU beer and blended prior to fermentation.

Comment: Good point, a sieve would be useless. I think your idea to double the batch is excellent, but would you have to do it quickly to avoid delaying the start of fermentation? It will be interesting to know the outcome your ooops! moment.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would have been to add additional malt extract to help counteract the bittering of the hops I imagine. Mind you, you'd end up with a pretty high gravity IPA doing that.

Did you bottle the beer? I'd like to know how it turns out!

Comment: Or add extract and dilute with water to lower gravity.